# MYSQL - Selecting the latest 3 records of each stock group

Tags: mysql

stock data

```
ticker  date         open   high    low     close   volume
--------------------------------------------------------------
AAA     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
AAA     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
AAA     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417
AAA     2014-06-13   0.715  0.715   0.705   0.71    36526

BBB     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
BBB     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
BBB     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417
BBB     2014-06-13   0.715  0.715   0.705   0.71    36526

CCC     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
CCC     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
CCC     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417
CCC     2014-06-13   0.715  0.715   0.705   0.71    36526
```

I want to select the latest 3 records of each stock, so that it would return the rows below from the table above like so;

```
AAA     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
AAA     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
AAA     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417

BBB     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
BBB     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
BBB     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417

CCC     2014-06-16   0.9    0.9     0.89    0.895   542
CCC     2014-06-15   1.32   1.33    1.31    1.32    2792
CCC     2014-06-14   1.19   1.25    1.19    1.25    417
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use user-defined variables to rank each record per ticker group and in outer select just filter them by rank

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT s.*,
@rank:= CASE WHEN @group = s.ticker THEN @rank +1 ELSE 1 END rank ,
@group:= s.ticker g
 FROM
`stock` s
JOIN (SELECT @group:='',@rank:='') t
ORDER BY ticker  ,`date` DESC
) t WHERE t.rank <=3
```